# ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps not working as supposed to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

As we know If we have DB columns `created_at` and `updated_at`. 
Then Rails will **automatically** set those values when we create and update a model object.In my case these were working fine before.

But few days ago it stop working even i didn't do major change. i have these 2 Columns as it is but rails **not updating** them automatically now.

Here is my migration file.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :name,              :null => false, :default => ""  

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, :name,       :unique => true
  end
end
```

My Base Record is set as `true` already So it's supposed to be working.

```
pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps
=> true
```

But in Both cases it's giving me `created_at: nil`.
Even this model `timestamps` is also `true` and all seems fine in the project.

```
pry(main)> User.record_timestamps
=> true
```

I also try to Put it as false and then change it to `true`

```
pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
=> false

pry(main)> User.create(:name => "Jeff")
=> #<User id: 11, name: "Name", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Change it to `true` then.

```
pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = true
=> true

pry(main)> User.create(:name => "Jeff")
=> #<User id: 11, name: "Name", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

For Me in the Both case result is same.
What cause of this issue and how can i get automatically updated these `created_at` and `updated_at` by rails.

**Versions:**

`Rails: 4.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have set default timezone in 
project/config/application.rb

code for this would look something like this

`config.time_zone = 'Europe/London'
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`

You can find your suitable timezone string [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) under Constants > mapping.

After setting valid timezone, open your migration file and add `null: false` in front of `t.timestamps`

So

> t.timestamps

will became

> t.timestamps null: false

Now make sure to rollback this migration by `rake db:rollback` before running migration.

Now run migration by `rake db:migrate`

Now it should work fine.
Let me know if you are still facing this issue.